# ¿Como puedo almacenar un dato de una columna de una base de datos sqlite en una variable usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Tengo un problema estoy intentando sacar un valor de una base de datos en sqlite3 usando python:

```
import sqlite3

#Conexion a la base de datos
con = sqlite3.connect("basededatos.db")
cursor = con.cursor()

#Comprobar conexion a base de datos
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categorias (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,categoria TEXT)""")
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO categorias(categoria) VALUES ('Gastos generales')""")
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,dato TEXT, categoria TEXT)""")
cursor.close()

def agregar():
 titulo()
 print ("AGREGAR")
 con = sqlite3.connect("nucleocentral.db")
 cursor = con.cursor()

 """PIDE EL TIPO DE OPERACIÓN"""
 print("Elija la operación que quiere hacer")
 print("""
 [1] Gasto
 [2] Ingreso
 """)

 operacion = input("Ingrese su operación: ")
 """-------INGRESO--------"""
 if operacion == "2":
  """Nuestra la tabla categorias"""
  cursor.execute("SELECT categoria FROM categorias")
  mostrar_categorias = cursor.fetchall()
  print(mostrar_categorias)
  """Una vez que vemos la tabla elegiremos el dato"""   
  buscar_id = int(input("Elija una categoria: "))
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE id='%s'" % (buscar_id))
  resultado_busqueda = cursor.fetchall()
  print("ESTE ES EL REGISTRO ",resultado_busqueda)
```

Ahora es cuando tengo el problema, he intentado sacar el valor de la columna
categoría de la tabla categorías y guardarlo en una variable para posteriormente usar ese datos guardarlo en la tabla datos en su columna categoría.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español, te recomiendo, para que te pregunta sea mas fácil de encontrar, que agregues más información a los tags de la misma, como por ejemplo, la versión de python! Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los metodos `fetchone` o `fetchall` de SQLite devuelven tuples. En el caso del `fetchall` que estás usando, al conseguir varios registros, tienes que iterar sobre esos tuples de la siguiente manera.

```
for record in resultado_busqueda:
   print(record)  # Así conseguirías todos los registros.
   print(record[1])  # Así, consigues solo la columna que especifiques
   print(record[1] + " del ID " + record[0])  # Así, consigues varias columnas
```

Como puedes comprobar, en nuestro segundo print solamente obtenemos el valor de la columna que queremos. No obstante, podemos ir más lejos y directamente guardar los datos en el orden que queramos (tercer print) para mejor uso.

Para guardar el valor de una columna en una variable, simplemente:

```
la_id = record[0]  
la_categoria = record[1]
```

Lo malo de hacer esto así es que necesitas conocer el index exacto de cada columna, y a veces es un poco lioso. Te sugeriría que mires algún ORM como [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) para python (Mapeadores de bases de datos). Así puedes hacer cosas como `la_categoria = record.categoria` y olvidarte de recordar el index de cada columna

Comment: Funciona bien pero he tendido que hacer lo siguiente:
 for record in resultado_busqueda:
    print(record[-1])
por que si no me daba el siguiente error:IndexError: tuple index out of range

Muchas gracias por tú ayuda

Comment: En caso de que la respuesta haya sido valida, por favor recuerda valorarla o aceptarla utilizando las flechas de la izquierda y el tick verde. Me alegro de haber podido ayudar.